# Dealing with single value hash or multiple value array in JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, hash

I have a JSON data feed where the value is a hash if single value and is an array if there are multiple values (see JSON data below).

JSON data:

```
# multiple values in option
{"options":{"option":[{"$t":"hasShots"},{"$t":"housebroken"}]}

# single value in option
{"options":{"option":{"$t":"hasShots"}}
```

I can do a check to see if the value is a hash or array using `is_a?` in Ruby, then extract the data accordingly and convert it to an object. Is this how it would typically be done or is there a better, more elegant way to code it in Ruby?

(NB: I figure this is such a common thing that there might be good solution to handling it. I google but it kept giving me how to parse JSON data's and creating JSON in Rails.)

Comment: Final goal  is what  ?

Comment: So "options" always has one item, and "option" can have multiple? What a horrid API!

Comment: Besides the fact `options` having one items and `option` having single or multiple which makes no sense, is it common for `option` to have a hash for a single value and then switch to an array for multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can do a check using `is_a?`. Is this how it would typically be done?

That's how I would do it! I think the more common scenario is for the JSON (or whatever) to have a consistent design, and have the objects in an array even if there's just one.